# How to get id from URL as variable? In Node.js

Tags: express

This is my express app running on Node.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('id: ' + req.query.id);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('working...');

//so i need url id as var
var gotID = req.query.id

//want to use this data to another js file
module.exports = gotID;
```

So I want that URL id as my variable.

Which is look like this URL

```js
http://localhost:3000/[id that i want]
```

So what should I do?

I'm new to Node.js

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send('id: ' + req.params.id);
});
```

req.query is used for search query parameters (i.e. everything after `?` in `http://something.com/path?foo=var`)

Comment: Thanks for help but i had problem about url. this sytanx http://something.com/path?foo=var didnt work  and i used like that http://something.com/path/var

Comment: If you need query parameters you should use `req.query`. `req.params` is for path parameters